# moovweb project not found

Tags: project, moovweb

By trying to start the server with "moov server" (windows) I got the error message "The path (here comes the address on my pc) does not point to a valid Moovweb project". How can I find out where my project is located - if it is somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a project first before you can run the server.

Use `moov generate` to create a project in the current directory.  Then `cd` into that directory and run `moov server` from within there.